# Why does invalid code annotated by `#[cfg(test)]` still cause the build to fail?

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation

Running `cargo build` will succeed for the following code:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn func() { 
        let x = 1;
        sss
    }
}
```

but will fail for this code:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn func() {
        sss
        let x = 1;
    }
}
```

```
error: expected `;`, found keyword `let`
 --> src/lib.rs:5:12
  |
5 |         sss
  |            ^ help: add `;` here
6 |         let x = 1;
  |         --- unexpected token
```

A section of the Rust Book on [Test Organization](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html?highlight=%23%5Bcfg(test)%5D#the-tests-module-and-cfgtest) says:

> The `#[cfg(test)]` annotation on the tests module tells Rust to compile
> and run the test code only when you run `cargo test`, not when you run
> `cargo build`.

So why does Rust still compile `mod tests` that is annotated with `#[cfg(test)]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code that is not compiled with `cfg` must still be syntactically valid (i.e. parse sucessfully), but nothing more than that.

In the first code, `let x = 1;` is a normal variable declaration statement, and `sss` is a trailing expression returning the value of `sss` from the function. `sss` is not defined, and thus of course this code is not valid, but it is *syntactically* valid.

In the second snippet, however, you have `sss` - that is an expression, and must have a trailing semicolon, but it doesn't. This code is not syntactically valid, and the fact that it is `cfg`-gated does not  matter.